# Is it possible to iterate through a conditional statement for the length property in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, for-loop, iteration

Thanks for taking your time to look at this. Code is below.

```
let questions = [];

let Question = function(question, answers, number) {
    this.question = question;
    this.answers = answers;
    this.number = number;
}

let question1 = new Question('Is Javascript the best programming language?', 
['No', 'Yes'], 1);

let question2 = new Question('Is Javascript a web development language?', 
['No', 'Yes'], 1);

let question3 = new Question(`What is Javascript's official server side 
application called?`, ['BootStrap', 'Python', 'Node.js'], 2);

questions = [question1, question2, question3];

Question.randomQuestion = function() {
    let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    let randomQuestion = questions[randomNum];

    return randomQuestion;
}

Question.display = function(randomQuestion) {
    console.log(randomQuestion.question);
    debugger;
        // Why does the conditional give me undefined?
        for (let i = 0; i < questions[i].answers[i].length; i++)
        console.log(`${randomQuestion.answers[i]}`);    
    }
```

What I'm trying to do is get the length of the answers property through each iteration but I get an error: answers is undefined. Why is it undefined, and is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You're applying the index `i` to both the question array and each question's `answer` property, and that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit on that?

Comment: `questions[i].answers[i]` means "the i'th answer to the i'th question`.  Is that really what you want? Shouldn't you iterate through the questions with one index and then through the answers for each question with another index?

Comment: your for loop should look like this `for (let i = 0; i < randomQuestion.answers[i].length; i++)`

Comment: @Pointy From what I understand is wrong in questions[i].answers[i].length, is that answers[i] is asking for a specific element in the array and than calling the length property which makes no sense, hence why it's undefined? Sorry, I just wanted to hash it out to clarify things!

Comment: @Guywhotypesfast Wouldn't that just get the length of the answers for one question and not all?

Comment: @Guywhotypesfast no, that's not right. The value of `answers[i]` from a given question is a *string*.

Comment: mm, you are right, he needs a second for loop to iterate through questions and then iterate through answers

Comment: Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of errors. Basically when you are iterating through two arrays you need two loops.
I've made this snippet with my code, hope it helps :

```js
let questions = [];

let Question = function (question, answers, number) {
  this.question = question;
  this.answers = answers;
  this.number = number;
}

let question1 = new Question('Is Javascript the best programming language?',
  ['No', 'Yes'], 1);

let question2 = new Question('Is Javascript a web development language?',
  ['No', 'Yes'], 1);

let question3 = new Question(`What is Javascript's official server side 
application called?`, ['BootStrap', 'Python', 'Node.js'], 2);

questions = [question1, question2, question3];

const randomQuestion = function () {
  let randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
  let randomQuestion = questions[randomNum];
  return randomQuestion;
}

const display = function (randomQuestion) {
  const random_question = randomQuestion();
  console.log(random_question.question);
  //debugger;
  // Why does the conditional give me undefined?
  //dump all question and all answers
  for (let i = 0; i < questions.length; i++)
    for (let j = 0; j < questions[i].answers.length; j++)
      console.log(`${questions[i].answers[j]}`);
  //as an alternative :
  questions.forEach(e => {
    console.log(e.question);
    e.answers.forEach(a => {
      console.log(a)
    })
  })
}

display(randomQuestion);
```